# My event click doesn't work

Tags: jquery, events, click

My code doesn't work ... someone can help me?

```
function main() {

    var myvar = 'cool', myvar2 = 'good';

    $("#list").append("<li><a class='execute' href=#SMSCONTOUT?telefone=" + myvar + "<h4>" + myvar2 + "</h4></a></li>");

    $(".execute").click(function () {
        $("#SMSCONTOUT").css("display", "block"); 
    });
}
```

my `$(".execute")` doesn't work ... my div: "SMSCONTOUT" doesn't appears ...

Comment: missing `;` after `myvar2`

Comment: what error do you get, Fiddler or Chrome Dev tools should tell us

Comment: Do you ever call `main()`?

Comment: @ChrisRockwell yeah ...

Comment: @RedSoxFred no error ... simply doesn't work

Comment: Then it should work: http://jsfiddle.net/SKG5f/1/

Comment: Can you show the rest?

Comment: What browser are you testing in?

Comment: You're still not showing us everything: http://jsfiddle.net/VuM9R/ I'll I have to do is add in `main()` and it runs

Comment: @ChrisRockwell here ==> http://jsfiddle.net/SKG5f/1/

Comment: @user2647038 that fiddle you posted works fine in Chrome

Comment: @Pitchinnate that's my fiddle, I don't know why he/she linked to it.  Notice how I call `main()`, which the OP is apparently not going to show :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this(You forgot the semicolon as well `;`):-

```
function main(){
var myvar, myvar2;

$("#list").append("<li><a class='execute' href='#SMSCONTOUT'?telefone="+myvar+"<h4>"+ myvar2 +"</h4></a></li>");

$("#list").on("click", ".execute", function(){
        alert(myvar);  
    });}
```

**EDIT**

Please look at the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VuM9R/)(Added by **Chris Rockwell**). This works fine!!!

Comment: @ChrisRockwell:- In that case only semicolon **;** should be corrected. I have seen your JSFiddle. Works fine!!!

Comment: The semicolon isn't necessary, that won't cause it to not run

Comment: I agree it's best practice, just saying that it's not the root of the problem

Comment: @ChrisRockwell:- Fully agree Sir thats why I have just written that OP has forgot to write that ;)

Comment: I think I misunderstood your first comment, sorry about that :)

Comment: @ChrisRockwell:- Dont be sorry Sir. I have seen your JSFiddle(latest)..I was doing the same. And it works!!! Dont know what OP is looking for. :)

Comment: @user2647038:- Please check  out the http://jsfiddle.net/VuM9R/ (added by Chris Rockwell)

Comment: @user2647038:- You are welcome. You can also thanks Chris. And dont forget to acccept this as an answer!!

Comment: @ChrisRockwell:- That worked for OP Sir!!!! Added for JSFiddle in answer as well:)

Answer (score 3):

Event delegation my friend:

```
$("#list").on("click", ".execute", function(){

    alert(myvar);

});
```

Comment: Why is event delegation needed in this case?  It appears that `.execute` already exists before the event handler is attached.  If so, why would changing to this fix anything?

Comment: Cause the link with the class `.execute` on it didn't exist when the DOM was created. It was added after the fact by javascript.

Comment: @ChrisRockwell ... cool but i've edited to the real question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your not closing your `<a>` tag after `myvar` and before `<h4>`, and I would put `href` value is quotes:

```
$("#list").append("<li><a class='execute' href='#SMSCONTOUT?telefone=" + myvar + "'><h4>" + myvar2 + "</h4></a></li>");
```

Currently the output html that is appended looks like this:

```
<a class='execute' href=#SMSCONTOUT?telefone=help<h4>yep</h4></a>
```

Some browsers are better at auto correcting for these types of mess ups than others.

After Edit, just use:

```
$("#SMSCONTOUT").show();
```